# What activity is called when I remove batery?

Tags: android

I need to remove user from my database if users phone turned off? I can't find a way to remove user from database if his phone died (for example if I take away phone batery or my phone falls on floor) user will still be reported in my game as "Online" even tho his phone died.

How do I remove user from database if his phone crashed for some reason. It's not onDestroy, onStop ...

Comment: how are you going process this event if your phone has no power to execute the code?

Comment: https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802

Comment: @DroiDev this could be something

Comment: look at cloud fucntions.... easiest way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

> What activity is called when I remove batery?

None.

> user will still be reported in my game as "Online" even tho his phone died.

If your server has not heard from the user after some period of time, the server can assume that the user is no longer in the game: the phone died, the phone lost Internet connectivity, etc.

Comment: Yes, however, where should I write that service?

Comment: @ObračunPlaće the server, where else?

Comment: Seems like it could be done with Firebase Cloud without server